# Why can I not determine my ruby installation's version?

Tags: ruby, nameerror

When I run `ruby -version` I get:

```
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin11.0]
-e:1: undefined local variable or method `rsion' for main:Object (NameError)
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: strange enough, `ruby --version` returns no errors.

Comment: The principle problem with your installation is that ruby 1.8.7 is end of lifed and unsupported now. Besides that, @R_G already explained that your `ruby -version` is equivalent to `ruby -v -e 'rsion'`.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Use either ruby -v or ruby --version.  It's parsing the -version into rsion.

Either of these two work.  Count the number of dashes:

```
ruby -v
ruby --version
```

When you provide a single dash with "version", Ruby sees this:

```
ruby -v -e rsion
```

Answer (score 8):

> There is a **-v** option and a **--version** option, but no -version option. 
>   (Count the dashes.) Look [**undefined local variable or method 'rsion' for main:Object**](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/306318).

From this [thread](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/306321), actual reason is much clear :

> If you run `ruby -version`, since you only use a single dash, the word
>   'version' isn't treated as a single flag but instead as a list of flags. In
>   this case, it picks up the -v flag, which prints the version information.
>   Then it tries to process the e flag, which basically says "the rest of this
>   line is a ruby script to execute." So ruby faithfully attempts to parse
>   "rsion", which is where you're getting the NameError.
>
> To just get the version info, you can do `ruby -v` or `ruby --version`.

Comment: Ahah, that is pretty amazing, your answer did make me understand the exact error, even though the link does sadly not work anymore (option v and option e exists and option e is trying to launch a command, and `rsion ` is not a valid command (`ruby -v` + `ruby -e` with arguments 'risen' = `ruby -version`)

Comment: @b.enoit.be Nice breaking the parts.

Answer (score 0):

That's just the way the interpreter is but you have constants defined in Ruby also.

Try

```
$> ruby -e " p RUBY_VERSION"
```

You can find then under Module.constants

here

```
>> Module.constants.sort.each do |constant| 
?>   puts constant
>> end
```